# Pushing applications to erlang slave nodes

Tags: logging, mapreduce, erlang, distributed, master-slave

In a [distributed system](http://discoproject.org) there is a master which starts a
bunch of slaves with slave:start.  It is using [lager](https://github.com/basho/lager) for logging the messages on
the master, the clients send log messages to the master and the master logs them.

The problem is that the number and size of these messages can grow and increase
the network usage.  Instead, I'd like the logs on the slave nodes to be written
locally instead of being pushed to the master unless the 'level' of the log 
message is higher than a certain level (e.g. error or alert but not warning).

I tried starting an independent lager application on the slave nodes, but it complains
about not finding the application file for it:
error,{"no such file or directory","goldrush.app"}
(goldrush is a dependency of lager).

How should these applications be distributed to the slaves?

Answer (score 1):

Applications should preferably be distributed as part of an Erlang release. This means creating a release with [Rebar](http://www.rebar3.org/). With such a process you would ensure you always have the applications you need (if your application correctly depends on other applications, like Lager).

Another option would be to ensure the application (and its dependencies) exist on the target system before launching it. This is a more manual approach, but could for example be to pull the source repo and run `rebar3 compile` among other commands to get the system built correctly. Once all dependencies are downloaded and built, you could launch the system.

There is no way to push Erlang applications to another node via Erlang itself. It is possible via trickery to send individual Erlang modules over the wire as binaries. This is *not advisable* for applications because they can depend on so much else (like application files and private data).

**Bottom line:** You need to ensure the application and its dependencies exist on the target yourself, via your own deployment procedure.